# ASP.Net MVC Core - working on multiple sessions objects (not objects in sessions, but sessions themselves)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core

I have the following need :

I would like to be able to apply a modification on the Session object of all connected users of my app when a specific event (triggered by a random component of my application) is raised.

For this, when a users log in the application I am subscribing to the event with a custom method for the specific session of the user. So I instantiate my listener and call my subscription method.

```
SecurityChangeListener securityChangeListener = new SecurityChangeListener();
securityChangeListener.SubscribeForUserSession(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session);
```

Where securityChangeListener is my listener class, and the listener class have the following implementation :

```
public class SecurityChangeListener
{
    private ISession _session;       

    public void SubscribeForUserSession(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;

        EventsHub.MyEvent += MyHandler;

        Logger.Info("Subscribed to event for session " + _session.Id);
    }

    private void EventsHubOnParameterElementChanged(object sender, EntityChangeEventArgs<IParameterElement> e)
    {
        Logger.Info($"Executing handler for session {_session.Id}");

        _session.Remove("MyKey1");
    }
```

}

The actual code is longer, but I kept only main excerpts.

The event is properly hooked to the listener, the event is called as expected for the specific session of each of my users.

But the "Session.Remove" does not act as expected :
If I look in debug what happens, the key is removed (present before, disappeared after) on the local "_session" object in the event method. 
**But when the rest of the program resumes, the key is back like if I ddi nothing on the session.**

Apparently the "_session" object is just some kind of copy of the actual session, and not a reference to the original session object itself.

Is there a way to manage sessions in ASP.Net Core as I am attempting to do, or more generally a way to access to the list of all existing sessions and alter their content ? 
I was not able to find anything related to session management in MVC Core.

Thanks for help

Comment: Sessions are a combination of server-side and client-side components. One means nothing without the other. Depending on your session store, somewhere there's a table or dictionary of sessions, but the actual data there is meaningless without the cookie from the client. In short, you can only meaningfully operate on a session while the user is actively using that session, within the context of a request from that user.

Comment: @ChrisPratt. Understood, thanks. FYI I am using "default" session storage, which should look like "InProc" old way. I was thinking the cookie on user side was only to "identify" him and link him to his session. With my current implementation, "_session" allows me to access to all informations about the session I am attempting to modify, even if it's not the one of the "acting" user so that tends to show the session is stored on the server and available also for non logged users. If I am wrong, do you have another approach to suggest to allow me to achieve my goal ? Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried to add a new key at the same place, and checked what happens with it? And at the 2nd request, is the removed key still there?

Comment: Hello @LGSon, I just did the test and I confirm that I am able to add and read a new key and its content in all "captured" session by my listener, but when the application resumes (including for my connected user) the new key have disappeared.

Comment: Through your listener it appears, yes, but what with another part of your code, during a user request. Are keys persistent and readable somewhere else?

Comment: No. But I can find it again the next time I enter in listener, which tends to prove the the "_session" variable captured by the listener is a value copy of the original session, that lives separately to it.